# using repeating scope data in onclick

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="x in hlist">
    <a onclick={{'swapContent(' + x.loc + ')'}} >{{x.h_label}}</a>
</div>
```

The code snippet is part of a menu, creating a dropdown menu portion from data in the AngularJS scope.  This successfully creates the menu items, but I have been unable to get it to pass scope data to the function.  Literal data passes through and works.

I have tried quite a few variants already, and am out of ideas.

- The scope data is an array of data, each "line" consisting of a location and a label
- I wish to have the menu display the label (working), and for it to pass the location to a function, which will then use the location info to get the desired content.

I get: 
    Easter

(It's a holiday site, Easter being one of them)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `ng-click` directive? Instead of using `onclick=`, try `ng-click="swapContent(x.loc)"`

(I'm assuming swapContent is a function defined in some controller scope elsewhere in your app.)